# Does Entity Framework 4 have a Contains feature?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Right now I am using an extension to linq to provide me with the functionality of Contains. I call the WhereIn like this:

```
Answers = Answers.WhereIn(x => x.category.catid, catSTRarray);
```

Is there a built in function within entity framework to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pseudo code

```
Answers.Where(x => catSTRarray.Contains(x.category.catid));
```