# Linq to entities with Any returns error

Tags: linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

I use Entity Framework 5 in an MVC application. I save a list of matches and before I do the actual update, I want to load all posted matches into the EF memory.

I have the following code (which works). _context is my EfDbContext:

```
public bool UpdateMatches(IEnumerable<Match> matchesToUpdate, int userID)
{
    matchesToUpdate = matchesToUpdate as List<Match> ?? matchesToUpdate.ToList();
    var matchIDs = matchesToUpdate.Select(m => m.ID).ToArray();

    _context.Matches.Where(x => matchIDs.Contains(x.ID)).Load();
}
```

But what I actually want is something like this:

```
public bool UpdateMatches(IEnumerable<Match> matchesToUpdate, int userID)
{
    _context.Matches.Where(m => matchesToUpdate.Any(x => x.ID == m.ID)).Load();
}
```

But I'm getting the error

> "Unable to create a constant value of type 'Matches'. Only primitive
>   types or enumeration types are supported in this context."

I also tried it with Contains, but no luck. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get list of `ID` from your `matchesToUpdate` collection and use `Contains` instead of `Any`:

```
public bool UpdateMatches(IEnumerable<Match> matchesToUpdate, int userID)
{
    var ids = matchesToUpdate.Select(x => x.ID).ToList();
    _context.Matches.Where(m => ids.Contains(m.ID)).Load();
}
```

It will result in `IN` statement within generated SQL query.

Comment: Hi Marcin, thanks! This works indeed, just like my 1st example. But it's not possible to do it in one line? You always have to retrieve a list of id's first?

Comment: ok, too bad. And what is this about then? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846013/does-entity-framework-4-have-a-contains-feature

Comment: It's pretty the same as yours - there is a list or array with items and it is checked with `Contains`.

Comment: Oh, I see, catSTRarray seems like an array :-). Thanks for the quick replies!